# Is it possible to get a JLabel to appear on the same GUI after a button click?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have a JList with a `setSelectedIndex(-1)`. I have a JButton , "More Details" which only works if an option is selected from the JList. If no option from the JList is selected and "More Details" is pressed, nothing happens, which is expected. But as a user you want to know when that button should be pressed.

A simple JLabel with the instruction saying "Select an option to obtain more details" would suffice. However, is there a way to get the JLabel to appear on the gui with the instruction after "More Details" is clicked? I do not want the instruction to be on the GUI all the time, as the "More Details" JButton will be rarely used. As a result of this I was wondering if it is possible to place text on the same GUI the button is located on with the instructions?

Comment: Disable the JButton until an option is selected from the JList.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might depend a little bit on the LayoutManager you use, but all JComponents have a method `setVisible(boolean)`. With this, you could in your ActionListeners for the JButton just call `myLabel.setVisible(true)`.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite possible. You could actually add your JLabel directly in your GUI and call setVisible(false) before showing it. When you hit the button and you want to show it, call setVisible(true)

Also, another way you can do this... Easier in many ways - is to use JOptionPane to pop up a warning / error message

Answer (score 0):

> nothing happens, which is expected. But as a user you want to know when that button should be pressed.

Use `ListSelectionListener` to monitor when the selection changes in the `JList` and enable/disable the button as required.